# Javascript in batch file to reposition IE window

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer, resize, window

I am trying to create a batch file and embed Javascript so that it opens an IE window at a specific size and location. I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597083/batch-file-open-windows-and-resize-them) and have also read about using Powershell and installing Node.js, however I need to be able to run it from a basic batch file.

I know that I can use (from [this Microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/making-an-ie-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-window/6c3dc8c7-5753-4a6f-bdfc-35e834f18836))

```
javascript:resizeTo(960,760);moveTo(73,63)
```

And add that as a favorite to change the window size and location.  Would I be able to somehow embed in a batch file or import to a batch file *without* running powershell, installing node.js, etc?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/768742/batch-file-to-open-4-or-6-internet-explorer-screens-and-place-them-by-dividing-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392620/how-can-a-batch-file-run-a-program-and-set-the-position-and-size-of-the-window), it seems that Batch can't do this. But PowerShell can. You could check [this article](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-the-position-and-size-54853527) and [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Open-Internet-Explorer-in-d91674ca#content).